# Do I need teflon tape (or something else) for a plastic shower head?

Tags: plumbing

I bought a plastic shower head from home depot for $1.97. It said hand tighten. When I got home I could not find my teflon tape. I installed the new shower head by hand tightening very tightly and it seemed to seal good.

Should I use teflon tape? [Should I use pipe thread compound as if I was attaching metal to PVC](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/62233/1679)?

Comment: Be careful not to over-tighten, it's really easy to split the threaded part of those cheap plastic shower heads. Maybe leave it be now, it's not leaking. Even if you *should* have used Teflon... "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most shower heads seal to the shower arm using a rubber washer. If that's the case with yours, the purpose of the threads is more to hold the washer tight, not provide a seal, and teflon tape or thread sealant compound are not useful.

Comment: On the other hand, I've seen many plastic fixtures where it wasn't possible to screw them down tight enough to form a good seal with the rubber washer, in which case the white tape *may* be useful.

Comment: I agree with @Craig. While it may not be required, PTFE tape couldn't hurt. The primary function of PTFE tape (and pipe dope) is to reduce friction, which allows you to tighten the joint a bit more.