# Can pipe dope be used on water lines in a vanity

Tags: plumbing

Does it hurt if I use pipe dope on water lines connecting a faucet in a vanity?

Comment: While is does not address the "safe" aspect, the following Q/A point out many relevant points on dope and when it is appropriate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/when-should-pipe-dope-vs-thread-tape-be-used. I personally know of no reason why pipe dope can't be used for a vanity - but I've only used tape or just relied of the fittings without.

Comment: Pipe dope is for lubrication, rather than sealing, but here's one hypothetical drawback: pipe dope could conseal a flaw in the connection. It would be better to know that the connection was poor before finding out by having the pipe dope fail a week later. With a finely threaded connection I think that the sealing capacity could become prominent, leading to the possibility of a cover-up.

Answer (score 2):

no - pipe dope can pretty much be used everywhere.  its not necessary though on anything but a thread to thread seal.  most vanities nowadays use flexible supply lines that have compression type fittings at either end with a rubber seal in them.  its not necessary on that connection at all.